# Getting updated server time every second

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have a requirement where I need to know what is the server time at a given point of time in the app. As soon as the app connects to server, the server sends back the time and I am not sure how to update this time.

I thought of using the timers where the method is called every second and and a second is added to server time, so that whenever I ask for server time it is always updated one. But problem with this if we schedule this on main runloop, the run loop may or may not process the timer request if there it is busy.

So how to track the server time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your server is in a specific time zone correct? Just get the time zone of the server using a request and show the time in that time zone in your app. You can then use a timer to continue updating the time every second.

I suggest getting just the time zone because if you get the server's time, there would be a lag between when the server sends back the response and when you get it - which defeats the whole purpose of getting the time as on the server.

Comment: I don't think I can make a server call every time to get the current time of the server. Once I receive this time for the first call, I ca n use timer object somehow in background thread and can update the same.

Comment: @user2273744 Timers in iOS are not real time, hence accuracy cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @Amar : Is there way to do this without using timers?

Comment: @user2273744 No, you will require a timer. But like lostInTransit said getting server timezone and using timer to update that time seems logical rather than getting time from server. Limitation here is that the accuracy of this time is bound to NSTimer accuracy which is not real time.

Comment: @Amar : Yes I can understand on this but if I use the timezone and local device time to calculate the time of the server, then there might be chance that this time may not be correct because user can go to settings page and can change the time and come back to app. This should not make any impact. I am afraid to read the device time.

Comment: If we are talking about the time in a time zone, it doesn't matter what the time is on the user's device. We are getting the server's time zone and showing the time to the user for the current time in that time zone. Whether the user's device is in GMT or EDT, doesn't make a difference as long as you know the server's time is in PDT.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't update the iOS system time from your app; there is no API
  for that.
- iPhone's time is usually very accurate. On iPads, it varies but has improved with iOS 5 to  +/- 5 seconds if some form of internet connectivity is available.
- If you want to manually connect to a server to synchronize time, you
  should do it in a background task.
- To compensate for latency, you should make multiple requests and add
  the average half of the roundtrip time to the time sent by the server.

However, the question remains: Why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: I am not updating the iOS system time. All I need to know the server time at a give point of time. Also I don't think it is good way to ask the server very time to know the server time.

Comment: Why not just store a `NSTimeInterval` of the offset (difference between server time and local time) then? You'd be able to calculate the presumptive server time whenever you want to by just adding the offset to the local time.

Comment: But the problem I can see here is user can change the time of device at any given point of time. If he does then all calculation gets wrong.

Comment: @user2273744 True, but you can't be sure to have absolutely synchronous time (on the device and the server) anyway. The time on the server could change, too. And there is always drift, latency etc. The ONLY way to be reasonably synchronous is to synchronize regularily. I think the actual question is: Why do you need to have the server time anyway?

Comment: My app will play the audio files from the server and these files needs to be in sync with what server is playing at a given point of time. This is basically a radio kind of app where user can post their audio casts and they will broadcasted in a queue fashion. The app should always keep the playing of files from server in sync with what is playing in the server. For this reason I should know the exact time of the server at a given point of time.

Comment: @user2273744 I suggest you update the title and description of your question to include this additional information, because that's an entirely different problem than you described. I'll try to add a new answer then.